# Display amzon.in product using api

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, rest, amazon-product-api

I am using Amazon e-commerce web service it's working well with Amazon.com and show all product from api but I want to display product from Amazon.in.

for API my base URL is

http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml

currently I am using this code

```
$base_url = "http://ecs.amazonaws.com/onca/xml";
$params = array( 'AWSAccessKeyId' => AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
                'AssociateTag' => AMAZON_ASSOC_TAG,
                'Version' => "",
                'Operation' => "ItemSearch",
                'Service' => "AWSECommerceService",
                'ResponseGroup' => "Accessories,ItemAttributes,Images,Variations,Reviews,Offers,OfferFull,OfferSummary,OfferListings,Medium",
                'Availability' => "Available",
                'Condition' => "New",
                'SearchIndex' => 'All',
                'ItemPage' => $page,
                'Keywords' => $searchTerm
        );
```

please tell me which URL should i use for Amazon.in

Answer (score 0):

Change the base url as follows  for indian market:

```
$base_url = "http://ecs.amazonaws.in/onca/xml";
```

And mention version in your request as:

```
"2011-08-01"
```